# to say that death is the end of life suggests that all living thing die?

Tags: logic, death

i'am currently reading "thinking clearly about death" by jay Rosenberg and in [1.3](https://books.google.de/books?id=UNmfc9_QsBAC&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=Thinking%20Clearly%20About%20Death%201.3&source=bl&ots=gkZAdTcUhg&sig=n75xrPFX_pg9MFflZP-adxlsoRM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAWoVChMI_LGZ5Z3RxwIVCw8sCh1qDwu7#v=onepage&q=Thinking%20Clearly%20About%20Death%201.3&f=false) (chapter 1 part 3) he says

> to say that death is the end of life suggests that all living thing die

it does not seem to me that "all living things die" follows from

"death is the end of the life"

unless we know "if something is living it will eventually stop living".

Comment: Well, he says *suggests*, not *implies*. The author is probably aware of the implicit assumption.

Comment: "Death is the end of life" if taken as a premise, presupposes "end of life" exists.

Comment: @KurtcebeEroglu under what grounds would one say that "end of life" does not exist?

Comment: I agree with you, the sentence itself doesn't suggest that, only our background assumptions on death do

Comment: @hellyale Assume that humankind achieved immortality. Then definition of Death would be "end of -some- life", or may be just "bad luck". "Death is the end of life", would not be a premise, it would be false, for there would exist some life for which death is not the end. On the other hand, if "death is the end of life" is a premise, then it's true. So "end of life" exists, for all; i.e. life ends for everyone; i.e. "if something is living, it will eventually stop living". Last sentence is premise that's said to be missing in the question, but it is actually there, presupposed by first premise.

Comment: @KurtcebeEroglu I have issue with starting from the assumption of immortality.

Comment: If we rule out other possibilities, then we already know "if something is living it will eventually stop living", hence second premise is not missing and conclusion follows. That seems to be another answer.

Comment: @KurtcebeEroglu "... for there would exist some life for which death is not the end."  True, but irrelevant, as  there would not exists any death that was not the end of life, which is the proposition under discussion.

Comment: An epigraph is a quotation at the front of a book.  Does it follow from that definition that every book has an epigraph?

Answer (score -4):

Don't think so, just because something has a end state does not mean it will ever reach it.
Don't think this is a good analogy but...

> to say that death is the end of life suggests that all living thing die.

I agree with you, just because death can occur to life, it does not mean that it will occur to life.

Take this (not very good) analogy for example

Let's say that life is like a dry woollen cloth, and death/the end of life is a soaked cloth.

If we submerge a dry woollen cloth in water it will get soaked, this is analogous to a living thing dying.

As long as someone does not submerge the woollen cloth in water it will not get soaked. Analogous to the life continuing. If the cloth never becomes submerged in water it will never get wet

That is all assuming that having a woollen cloth will soak it is a absolute fact

So just as a woollen cloth can be submerged in water and can get soaked, thus does not mean that it will be submerged in water, death being the end of life does not mean that all living things will die

But others have already noted, that is not implied in the statement, it merely states that life having an end **suggests ** that life will eventually end. 
In a sense it does but I think this is more due to the power of suggestion or something to do with our psychology.

Comment: Heh, I think *data* suggests that death is the end of life? Have you ever seen a living thing that doesn't / can't die?

Comment: @virmaior that is true but the statement " death is the end of life" should not suggest that.

Comment: @virmaior There are species of jellyfish that are speculated to be immortal in the absence of predation. There are other issues with this answer, but finite inductive "data" is not one of them.

Answer (score -5):

The conclusion follows from the premises:
   a)  all living things must have life to be alive.
   b)  for all living things, death is a transition from alive to dead.
       therefore, death (end of life), is the point at which a living thing dies.

Comment: Downvoted because (a) this doesn't attempt to answer the OP's question, and (b) the argument is plainly invalid.

Comment: @possibleWorld can you explain why this argument is invalid?

Comment: @possibleWorld maybe unsound, but you would have to explain that to me as well.

Comment: @Hellyale Sure: let 'Txyz' symbolize the relation 'x transitions from y to z', and let 'Pxy' symbolize the relation 'x dies at point (i.e. time) y. Then, assuming that we can quantify over states as well as objects, it's pretty routine to come up with an interpretation that makes the former formula true but the latter formula false.

Comment: @possibleWorld what is the z here? 
What routine formulation are you coming up with?